# Emacs on Windows: shell, Emacs not response when press Enter

Tags: shell, emacs

Windows 7 (64 bit)
Emacs 24.5.1

1. M-x
2. shell (screen#1)
3. Start some process that permanent scrolling some text (screen#2)
4. Move up by arrow (several screens) (screen#3)
5. Press Enter
6. Emacs not response (screen#4)

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean that Emacs does not respond to the `Enter` key press, or that when you press `Enter` Emacs crashes and becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Can you give more details about the process? Do you have the same issue when this process is started in a terminal?

Comment: I updated my post.
I mean "when press Enter, Emacs becomes unresponsive"